# GCP zone northamerica-northeast1-a does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

When I run `gcloud compute instances create test --zone=northamerica-northeast1-a` I get:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - The zone 'projects/PROJECT/zones/northamerica-northeast1-a' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request.  Try a different zone, or try again later.
```

I ran into this error in production where a service tried to spin up resources there.

This only affects that specific zone. Is there a way to get more information about this? Is this an outage?

Cheers,
Kim

Answer (score 4):

At the time you tried to provision the instance, that zone had insufficient resources to 'make it so'.

You may retry the request (please do so increasingly infrequently) until there are sufficient resources for you to acquire. There are others also trying to secure these resources and, everyone hammering the request concurrently exacerbates the issue.

There's only ever finite resources available and, unfortunately, you hit Google's capacity for that zone (for available resources to fulfill your need) for that period of time.

The error is unambiguous and you're unlikely to get much more from Google by way of admission that it had insufficient capacity (available) because customers don't want to experience this.

Answer (score 1):

Same start happen today with `northamerica-northeast1-c` does not have enough resources available.
It's bad , two of three zones out of resources.